# How can I make multiple requests in a row using riot-lol-api?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

**SITUATION:**

I had an existing codebase that used another library to make requests to the Riot API. Sadly, said library had some issues, so I decided to switch to this one:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/riot-lol-api

https://github.com/Neamar/riot-lol-api/blob/master/lib/index.js

Only issue: this library does not seem to use Promises while the old one did and I have a hard time adapting my code to this new library.

---

**CODE:**

```
var urls = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++) {
         urls.push('/lol/league/v3/positions/by-summoner/'+enemies[i].summonerId);
    }

    let promises = urls.map(url => fetchData(url, region, "league"));

    Promise.all(promises).then(responses => {

         console.log("RESPONSES: "+responses);
```

...

```
function fetchData(url, region, tag) {

// This used to be a promise when the old library was used

riotRequest.request(region.toLowerCase(), tag, url, function(err, data) {
    if (!err) {
        return data;
    } else {
        console.error("ERROR FIRST ITERATIONS: "+err);
        res.render("threat", {errorMessage: "Player not found ! The game must either have started or be on the loading screen.", finalPlayers: undefined});
    }
});

}
```

Now, of course, this does not work but consider it pseudocode to explain what I would like to achieve here.

---

**OUTPUT:**

```
RESPONSES: ,,,,
```

---

**QUESTION:**

How can I adapt my code to the new library ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I wrote the library, promises were really slow. Using promises allowed me to send 700 requests per second per CPU, without promises I got to 1000 requests per seconds per CPU.

If performance is not an issue in your case, you can transform the callback style functions to promises using this small wrapper:

```
let RiotRequest = require('riot-lol-api');

let riotRequest = new RiotRequest('<your-key>');

// This function will return a promise that you can then use with Promise.all
function promisifiedRequest(region, group, endpoint) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    riotRequest.request(region, group, endpoint, function(err, res) {
      if(err) {
        reject(err)
      }
      else {
        resolve(res);
      }
    })
  });
}

// Example use:
promisifiedRequest('euw1', 'summoner', '/lol/summoner/v3/summoners/by-name/graphistos').then(function(response) {
  console.log("Result:", response);
}).catch(console.log)
```

Comment: Great ! Thank you ! Since there is a performance cost to using promises, is there some way to achieve what I wanted to do without using promises ? (aka, multiple requests at the same time and responses received in the same order as requests ?)